# Error deploying Shiny app on shinyapps.io - Failed to determine "appPrimaryDoc"

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

Tried to Deploy Shiny app to shinyapps.io but encounter this message. What should I do?

---

```r
── Preparing for deployment ────────────────────────────────────────────────────  
✔ Deploying "R-shiny-assessment" using "server: shinyapps.io / username: xxx"  
Error in `inferAppPrimaryDoc()`:  
! Failed to determine `appPrimaryDoc`.  
✖ No files matching "\\.html?$".  
Backtrace:  
    ▆  
 1. └─rsconnect::deployApp(...)  
 2.   └─rsconnect:::appMetadata(...)  
 3.     └─rsconnect:::inferAppPrimaryDoc(appPrimaryDoc = appPrimaryDoc, appFiles = appFiles, appMode = appMode)  
 4.       └─cli::cli_abort(...)  
 5.         └─rlang::abort(...)  
Execution halted
```

---

My code:

---

```r
library(shiny)  
library(readxl)  
library(openxlsx)  
library(dplyr)  
library(tidyverse)  
library(ggplot2)  
library(rsconnect)  


ui <- fluidPage(  
  
  titlePanel("Claim Data Upload"),  
  
  sidebarLayout(  
    sidebarPanel(  
      sliderInput("tail_factor",label = "Please adjust Tail Factor",  
                  min = 1,max = 2,value = 1.1,step = 0.1),  
      
      fileInput(inputId = "file",label = "Upload your file",accept = ".xlsx")  
    ),  
    mainPanel(  
      tableOutput("content"),  
      plotOutput("graph"),  
    )  
  )  
)  
server <- function(input,output,session){  
  
  excel <- reactive({  
    req(input$file)  
    data.frame(read_excel(input$file$datapath))  
  })  
  
  output$content <- renderTable({  
    req(input$file)  
    data.frame(read_excel("testing.xlsx","sheet3"))  
  })  
  
  #Graph Creation  
    
  data2 <- read_excel("testing.xlsx","sheet3",skip = 1)  
  data2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(data2,as.numeric))  
  
  data2_long <- data2 %>%  
    gather(variable, value, -Loss_Year)  
  
  output$graph <- renderPlot({   
    req(input$file)  
    ggplot(data2_long, aes(x = variable, y = value, color = factor(Loss_Year), label = value,   group = Loss_Year)) +  
      geom_point() +  
      geom_line() +  
      geom_text(vjust = -0.5, hjust = 0.5) +    
      labs(title = "Cumulative Paid Claims ($)",  
           x = "Variable",  
           y = "Cumulative Paid Claim",   
           color = "Loss_Year")  
  })  
  
  observe({  
     
    wb <- createWorkbook()  
    
    addWorksheet(wb, "sheet1")  
    
    
    
#Create Loss Year Column  
    loss_year <- unique(data.frame(Loss_Year = excel()[, 1]))  
    writeData(wb, "sheet1", loss_year, xy = c("A", "3"))  
    
#Create Development Year row header  
    DY <- unique(data.frame(Development_Year = excel()[,2]))  
    DY_tail <- tail(DY$Development_Year, 1)+1  
    writeData(wb,"sheet1",as.data.frame(t(c(DY$Development_Year,DY_tail))),  
              xy = c("B", "2"),colNames = TRUE)  
    saveWorkbook(wb, "testing.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)  

    testing <- reactive({  
      data.frame(read_excel("testing.xlsx"))  
    })  
    
    #column Header Values for excel.xlsx  
    e_column1 <- excel()[,1]  
    e_column2 <- excel()[,2]  
    
    r <- 2  
    c <- 1  
    while(c+1 <= ncol(testing())-1){  
      while(r <= nrow(testing())){  
        triangle_input <- sum(excel()[e_column1 == testing()[r,1] & e_column2 <= testing()  [1,c+1],][,3])  
        writeData(wb, "sheet1", triangle_input, xy = c(c+1, r+2))  
        r <- r+1  
      }  
      c <- c+1  
      r <- 2  
    }  
    saveWorkbook(wb, "testing.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)  
    
    #Filter the repeated value at the end  
      
    
    filtered_triangle <- t(data.frame(read_excel("testing.xlsx")))  
    filtered_triangle <- apply(filtered_triangle, 2, function(x) ifelse(duplicated(x), NA, x[!duplicated(x)]))  
    filtered_triangle <- apply(filtered_triangle, 2, function(x) ifelse(duplicated(x), NA, x[!duplicated(x)]))  
    filtered_triangle <- t(filtered_triangle)  
    addWorksheet(wb,"sheet2")  
    writeData(wb,"sheet2",x = filtered_triangle)  
    saveWorkbook(wb, "testing.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)  
    
    addWorksheet(wb,"sheet3")  
    writeData(wb,"sheet3",x = filtered_triangle)  
    saveWorkbook(wb, "testing.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)  
    
    origin <- read_excel("testing.xlsx","sheet2",skip = 1)  
    origin[] <- lapply(origin,as.numeric)  
     
    updated_origin <- read_excel("testing.xlsx","sheet3",skip = 1)  
    updated_origin[] <- lapply(updated_origin,as.numeric)  
    
    r <- 1  
    c <- 2  
    while(c <= ncol(origin)-1){  
      while(r <= nrow(origin)){  
        
        column_sum <- sum(origin[,c],na.rm = TRUE)  
        non_na_indices <- which(!is.na(origin[, c]))  
        
        column_divide <- sum(origin[non_na_indices,c-1],na.rm = TRUE)  
        
        #PS: [[1]] is use to extract the first value from the tibble  
        multiply <- as.numeric((read_excel("testing.xlsx","sheet3",skip = 1)[r,c-1])[[1]])  
        
        
        if(is.na(origin[r,c])){  
          writeData(wb,"sheet3",x = round(column_sum*multiply/column_divide,2),xy = c(c,r+2))  
          
          saveWorkbook(wb, "testing.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)  
        }  
        r <- r+1  
      }  
      c <- c+1  
      r <- 1  
    }  
    
    r <- 1  
    c <- ncol(origin)  
    while(c <= ncol(origin)){  
      while(r <= nrow(origin)){  
        if(is.na(origin[r,c])){  
          estimate <- input$tail_factor*as.numeric((read_excel("testing.xlsx","sheet3",skip = 1)[r,c-1])[[1]])  
          writeData(wb,"sheet3",x = estimate,xy = c(c,r+2))  
          
          saveWorkbook(wb, "testing.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)  
        }   
        r <- r+1  
      }  
      c <- c+1  
      r <- 1  
    }  
  })  
}  



shinyApp(ui,server)  

rsconnect::deployApp('C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R-shiny-assessment')
```

---

What I had tried:

1. deploying the app at RStudio GUI:

---

```r
    library(rsconnect)
    setwd("C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R-shiny-assessment")
    rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='xxx', token='8531DA3C486C01599C7910D22EF44CDD', secret='xxx')
    rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R-shiny-assessment",appPrimaryDoc = 'Excel_Layout.R')
```

---

error message from log:

---

```
2024-01-30T00:57:29.488156+00:00 shinyapps[11068239]: Error in rsconnect::deployApp("C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R-shiny-assessment") : 
2024-01-30T00:57:29.492800+00:00 shinyapps[11068239]:   `appDir`, "C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R-shiny-assessment", does not
2024-01-30T00:57:29.497047+00:00 shinyapps[11068239]: exist.
2024-01-30T00:57:29.501337+00:00 shinyapps[11068239]: Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
2024-01-30T00:57:29.505803+00:00 shinyapps[11068239]: Execution halted
```

---

Comment: You need to run `rsconnect::deployApp()` but it shouldn't be included in your app - you're asking your app to deploy the app when it runs. You should call that function from outside of the app. If it's your first go, I'd suggest using the GUI inside Rstudio

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the suggestions. I deployed the app in RGUI and received another error in my log saying my App Directory was not found. Had updated the information in the question.

Comment: Presumably your windows user name is not `xxx`? I was meaning for you to use this which doesn't need you to write any code to deploy: https://docs.posit.co/shinyapps.io/getting-started.html#deploying-your-first-application